# Can the GPS be emulated in Android on a real phone? (no emulator)

Tags: android, gps

To test an app I'm building, I want to be able to emulate the GPS location on a real device, not connected to a computer.

Is that possible?
I found several ways to do this using the emulator, but none for a real device.

Thanks

Comment: just checking.. it sounds like you want to run your app ON an android device, but with emulated GPS radio data, rather than from the actual GPS?

Comment: Correct (will edit), and I want to build the emulator myself (for automation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In System settings > Developer options, enable "Allow mock locations".

Then use app like "[My Fake Location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.fake.location&hl=en)" to set the fake location.

Comment: That works, but I need to build the emulator myself for automation purposes

Comment: check google play, there's actually an app called GPS route simulator: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forgottenprojects.mocklocations&feature=search_result that will run a point to point path, or even run along a kml file over a given timeframe. so @Janhouse has an answer that is good to accept as correct.